# How to run scp on ec2

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, scp

I'm trying to copy file from server to server by running scp command on ec2.

```
**My command:**
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xxx ~]$ scp -P 51865 user@207.154.xx.xx:/home/yakir/tr/tracker-2019-12-12.tar.gz ec2-user@ec2-3-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/tracker-2019-12-12.tar.gz
```

**The error is:**

```
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

What should i do to get it works?

Thanks!

Comment: Running the same command on my machine is working (just waiting for the server response because I entered a fake IP). What OS are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

ssh to server and run scp

```
ssh -P 51865 user@207.154.xx.xx "scp /home/yakir/tr/tracker-2019-12-12.tar.gz ec2-user@ec2-3-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/tracker-2019-12-12.tar.gz"
```

Comment: Thanks!
I run this:
ssh user@207.154.219.xx -p 51865 "scp -P 51865 yakir@207.154.219.93:/home/yakir/tr/tracker-2019-12-12.tar.gz ec2-user@ec2-3-227-251-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/test/"

But now i got the error below:
Host key verification failed.